# Why doesn't framework detour?

Tags: moles

I am unit testing code that depends on iTextSharp open source Pdf library. One of the classes inTextSharp is PdfReader with one of the constructors that accepts byte array. I simplified the problem to the following:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [HostType("Moles")]
    public void ReadPdf()
    {
        MPdfReader.ConstructorByteArray = (@this, pdfIn) =>
        {
            new MPdfReader(@this)
            {                    
            };
        };

        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new byte[] { 10, 20, 30 });
    }
```

However, this code still calls the real PdfReader and not the mock:

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.CheckPdfHeader
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader.ReadPdf()
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn, Byte[] ownerPassword)
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(Byte[] pdfIn)

and not surprisedly, it blows up with "..System.IO.IOException: PDF header signature not found..    "

Not sure what I'm doing wrong....

-Stan

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are attempting to defuse the constructor call that accepts a byte array.  Try removing the instance parameter in your constructor overload:

```
[TestMethod]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void ReadPdf()
{
    MPdfReader.ConstructorByteArray = (@this, pdfIn) =>
    {
        new MPdfReader()
        {
        };
    };
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new byte[] { 10, 20, 30 });
}
```